# Js issue in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-6

I have a problem with js issue in laravel. Here is my code.

**Controller**:

```
CollectionController :

public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $collections = new Collections() ;

        $collections->collectionNo = dechex(uniqid());

        $collections->campus = $request->campus ;
        $collections->groups = $request->group ;
        $collections->class = $request->class ;
        $collections->section = $request->section ;

        $collections->studentId = $request->studentId ;
        $collections->studentName = $request->studentName ;
        $collections->studentRoll = $request->studentRoll ;

        $collections->feesCode = $request->feesCode ;
        $collections->feesAmount = $request->feesAmount ;
        $collections->noOfMonth = $request->no_of_month ;
        $collections->paidAmount = $request->paidAmount ;
        $collections->discountAmount = $request->lessAmount ;
        $collections->totalFeesAmount = $request->totalFeesAmount ;
        $collections->dueAmount = $request->dueAmount ;

        if($request->paidAmount > $request->totalFeesAmount){
            $collections->returnAmount = $request->paidAMount - $request->totalFeesAmount ;
        }else{
            $collections->returnAmount = 0 ;
        }

        $collections->remarks = $request->remarks ;

        if($request->addCollection){
            $collections->save();
            echo 'Fee collected successfully';
        }else{
            $data['collections'] = Collections::all();
            $data['campuses']    = CommonController::getCampus() ;
            $data['classes']     = CommonController::getClass() ;
            $data['sections']    = CommonController::getSection() ;
            $data['groups']      = CommonController::getGroup() ;
            $data['fees']        = CommonController::getFee() ;
            $data['transport']   = CommonController::getTransport() ;

            return view('collections/addCollection')->with($data);
        }
    }
```

**View**:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <div class="card">
            <form id="searchById" class="form">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Student ID</label>
                            <input id="studentId" class="form-control" name="id" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collectionStudentInfo" class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Campus</label>
                            <input id="collectionCampus" class="form-control" name="campus" value="" placeholder="Campus"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Class</label>
                            <input id="collectionClass" class="form-control" name="class" value="" placeholder="Class"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Group</label>
                            <input id="collectionGroup" class="form-control" name="group" value="" placeholder="Group"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Section</label>
                            <input id="collectionSection" class="form-control" name="section" value="" placeholder="Section"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Student Name</label>
                            <input id="collectionStudentName" class="form-control" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Roll No.</label>
                            <input id="collectionStudentRoll" class="form-control" name="roll" value="" placeholder="Roll No"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>SMS No.</label>
                            <input id="collectionStudentContact" class="form-control" name="contact" value="" placeholder="SMS No."/>
                        </div>
            </form>
            {{-- end --}}
            <div class="card-header">Add Fee Collection</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form class="addledger form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/collection/create')}}">
                    @php
                    if(Session::has('message')){
                        $msg = "Fee Collection record Successfully" ;
                        echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$msg.'</p>' ;
                    }
                    elseif (Session::has('error')) {
                        $error = "Something Went Wrong. Operation unsuccessful" ;
                        echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">'.Session::has('error').'</p>' ;
                    }
                    @endphp

                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label>Student ID</label>
                                <input id="studentId" class="form-control" name="id" value="" autocomplete="off"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collectionStudentInfo" class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label>Campus</label>
                                <input id="collectionCampus" class="form-control" name="campus" value="" placeholder="Campus"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label>Class</label>
                                <input id="collectionClass" class="form-control" name="class" value="" placeholder="Class"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label>Group</label>
                                <input id="collectionGroup" class="form-control" name="group" value="" placeholder="Group"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label>Section</label>
                                <input id="collectionSection" class="form-control" name="section" value="" placeholder="Section"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>Student Name</label>
                                <input id="collectionStudentName" class="form-control" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>Roll No.</label>
                                <input id="collectionStudentRoll" class="form-control" name="roll" value="" placeholder="Roll No"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label>SMS No.</label>
                                <input id="collectionStudentContact" class="form-control" name="contact" value="" placeholder="SMS No."/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <label>Fee List</label>
                            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Sel</th>
                                        <th>Sl</th>
                                        <th>Fees Name</th>
                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="feeByStudent feetable">
                                 </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" id="feesAmount" name="feesAmount" placeholder="Enter Fee Amount" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" id="feesMonthNo" name="no_of_month" placeholder="Enter Fee Month No." class="form-control" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" id="totalFeeAmount" name="totalFeesAmount" placeholder="Enter Fee Amount" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" id="lessAmount" name="lessAmount" placeholder="Enter Less/Discount Amount" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" id="paidAmount" name="paidAmount" placeholder="Enter Fee Paid Amount" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" id="dueAmount" name="dueAmount" placeholder="Enter Due Fee Amount" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" id="remarks" name="remarks" placeholder="Enter Remarks" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" id="text1" class="btn btn-success" name="addCollection" value="Add">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Collect Fee
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"></div>
        </div>

        <script>

            $('#studentId').on('keyup',function () {
                    let id = $("#studentId").val() ;
                    console.log('ID is : ' + id) ;
                    $("#collectionStudentInfo").css("display", "block") ;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/getStudentById',
                        type: 'get',
                        dataType:'json',
                        contentType: 'json',
                        data: {studentId:id},
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (html) {

                            $('#collectionStudentName').val(html.student[0].name);
                            $('#collectionStudentRoll').val(html.student[0].roll);
                            $('#collectionCampus').val(html.student[0].campus);
                            $('#collectionClass').val(html.student[0].class);
                            $('#collectionGroup').val(html.student[0].group);
                            $('#collectionSection').val(html.student[0].section);
                            $('#collectionStudentContact').val(html.student[0].contactNo);

                            let feetable = '';
                            for(i in html.fee){
                                feetable += '<tr>';
                                feetable += '<td class="feesCode"><input type="checkbox" id="feesCode" data-feesCode="'+html.fee[i].fees_code+'" name="feesCode[]" value="'+html.fee[i].feeAmount+'"/></td>' ;
                                feetable += '<td>'+html.fee[i].fees_code+'</td>' ;
                                feetable += '<td>'+html.fee[i].feesName+'</td>' ;
                                feetable += '<td>'+html.fee[i].feeAmount+'</td>';
                                feetable += '</tr>' ;
                            }

                            $('.feetable').html(feetable);

                        },

                        fail : function fail(){
                            console.log('Operation fail');
                        }
                    });
                });

            $(".schoolfee").click(function(e) {
                let myArray = 0 ;
                $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                    myArray = parseInt(myArray) + parseInt(this.value);
                });

                $('#feesAmount').val(myArray);
            });

            $("input[type=button][name='feesCode[]']").on('click',function () {
                let id = 0 ;
                id = $("input[type=checkbox][name='feesCode[]']").val() ;
                console.log(id);
                $.ajax({
                url: '/getFeeById',
                type: 'get',
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: 'json',
                data: {feeId:id},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (html) {
                    console.log(html);
                        $('#feesAmount').val(html[0].amount);
                        $('#dueAmount').val(html[0].dueAmount);
                },
                fail : function fail(){
                    console.log('Operation fail');
                }
            });
        </script>
@endsection
```

When I input student ID in input box, the fee table appears by using jquery `keyup` event. But the problem is that no jquery worked when I clicked on the table. In my code js part `$("input[type=button][name='feesCode[]']").on('click',function ()` does not work. Why this problem occurred and how can I fix it?
Here is the screenshot of the fee table
[image]

In the picture when I click on the checkbox, no event is triggered.

Here is the console.log screenshot
[image]

Comment: Share your console log first.

Comment: I share screenshot of console log in question.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$("input[type=button][name='feesCode[]']").on('click',function () {
```

to this

```
$(document).on('click', "input[type=button][name='feesCode[]']", function () {
```

Comment: Ok, so first you should fix html.student[0] errors. Are you sure you have this array in json data? Add `console.log(html)` inside ajax success event and double check data structure and names. Maybe you should check whether html.student is empty before accessing its value.

Comment: still not triggered when click on checkbox

Comment: Your selector on click event uses `type=button` which doesn't match your html code (checkbox). Besides it could be better to use change event on checkbox.

Comment: When I use type=checkbox same problem is occurred.